# How would I vs How I would

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

In the following sentence:

> One of the questions in a test I solved was about how would I organize the process if I was HR

Google grammar checker suggests that I should put "I would" instead "would I" there.
Which one is correct? Does this sentence make even sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct questions usually have an inverted word order where an auxiliary verb precedes the subject, e.g. "How would you do it?".

The question you were asked was:

> "How would you organise the process?"

But indirect questions embedded in subordinate clauses don't have this inversion:

> I was asked how I would organise the process.

> They asked me how I would organise the process.

> One of the questions was about how I would organise the process.

The only way that the inverted order would make sense would be if the question is separated off and remains in question form, usually (but not always) in quotation marks:

> One of the questions was: "How would you organise the process?"